# Disable average values on highchart line graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart that has months as the x-axis and displayed the values on mouse over.

There are a lot of months so when zoomed out fully the chart only has every third month with an average value of the months around that point.

Is it possible to change this so that it will display the exact value of the month displayed rather than an average as it is currently displayed different values when zoomed in to zoomed out.

You can see an example of this on http://www.highcharts.com/ on the USD to EUR chart where 2nd  May 2011 displays different values depending on zoom level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping)

Comment: Knew it would be something simple. Thanks.